# I am using subscribe method but getting an error in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, post

I am new to angular. I am using old subscribe method but getting an error

```
    PosttoServer(){
    var cusdto:any = {};
    cusdto.CustomerCode = this.CustomerModel.CustomerCode;
    cusdto.CustomerName = this.CustomerModel.CustomerName;
    cusdto.CustomerAmount = this.CustomerModel.CustomerAmount;

    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/posts",
    cusdto).subscribe(this.Success, this.Error);
  }

  Error(res){
    console.debug(res.json());
  }

  Success(res){
    this.CustomerModels = res.json();
  }
```

Error:

```
CustomerApp.CustomerComponent.ts:26 ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
    at Object.Error [as error] (CustomerApp.CustomerComponent.ts:31:23)
    at ConsumerObserver.error (Subscriber.js:102:33)
```

any suggestion how to use subscribe method.Thank you

Comment: where are parentheses when invoking this.Success() and this.Error() ?

Comment: @Vahid18u and what should I pass inside parentheses?

Comment: Do you have a backend listening on `http://localhost:3000/Customers`? `404 (Not Found)` looks like your backend doesn't handle the URL.

Comment: Yes I am using fake json_server. So that is taking care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add .json()
It should work

Comment: I removed  .json()  as per your suggestion. That error removed. Thank you mate for your help

Comment: That depends on the fake server implementation. if you are using 'json-server'. It should have posted. You shall give more clarity on the server implementation.